# Modelling the probability of dice

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

I'm an A-level student with not much skill in maths at the moment and this question stopped me:

[image: Question]

i thought of drawing a tree diagram but doing 30 of them! Not for me. There must be a quicker way on a calculator im using a fx-991EX classwiz please help.

Comment: Hint: Have you heard about Bernoulli tests and Binomial distributions?

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues   Ill go research them thanks!

Comment: If you need further help let me know

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues ive completed abc but ii) is confusing i  researched it and p values came up a lot, how would i go around doing this? P.S sorry i forgot about this post

Comment: English isn't my first language, so $(ii)$ gets a bit dirty to me, can you tell me what do you understand by "$5\%$ significance level" ? I see two ways possible of doing this, depending on the understanding of the question

Answer (score 0):

On each throw, there is a 1/6 chance of throwing a 6 and 5/6 chance of not throwing a 6.  So this is a binomial distribution with "p" equal to 1/6 and "q" equal to 5/6 and "n" equal to 30.  The probability of x sixes is
$\begin{pmatrix}30 \\ x\end{pmatrix}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^x\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{30- x}$